# Mysql/php connection

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm a newbie to ubuntu,and  im trying to connect the mysqlworkbench(database) with php5.3

```
if (function_exists('mysql_connect')) {
 echo "Good<br />\n";
} else {
echo "Bad.<br />\n";
}
```

I'm getting the output as Bad and then i tried with **mysqli_connect** ,that is also not exists in my scenario. Is there any way to solve this issue?

Thanks in Advance.. show some examples to tackle this

Comment: try mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");

Comment: That looks like what would happen if you compiled PHP yourself without MySQL support, which shouldn't be the case if you're using the PHP from Ubuntu.  Did you install PHP from the official packages?  Can you tell us how you installed PHP?

Comment: i tired this and there is no response. so i check the existence by function_exists('mysql_connect').. it gives as FALSE..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you've installed PHP and MySQL using regular Ubuntu packages. Then install the `php5-mysql` package to have MySQL bindings for PHP. E.g.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

You may need to restart your web server to make the changes effective.

Verify with a simple [phpinfo](https://www.php.net/phpinfo) PHP file the PHP-MySQL support (`mysqli` extension).

```
<?php

phpinfo();

?>
```

Comment: @gertvdijk...thanks a lot .. issue solved by istalling the package to bind the mysql with php